# Debug XAML in Visual studio 2015. Where is Live Visual Tree and Live Properties

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I downloaded the new Visual Studio 2015 CTP6 to test the new XAML debugging features - but I can't find them? I've read that those windows should open right after starting the debugging but they do not appear - anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This feature should be accessible in CTP6 in menu via Debug -> Windows -> Live Visual Tree

Answer (score 14):

Debug –> Windows –> Live Visual Tree | Live Property Explorer

[image]

In any case you cannot see them, check options.

[image]

See here for more details on [Inspect XAML properties while debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx) property.

Comment: What the option "Preview selected elements..." actually does?

Comment: Is it available in Visual Studio Professional 2013 ? I do not see the checkbox in Option dialog and Live Visual Tree in Windows Menu. Am I missing something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with VS2017 - which has new 'Live editing' of XAML that instantly is reflected in your running application.

First make sure you actually have XAML under text editor

[image]

If it isn't there (and you can't even open a XAML file in designer mode) you have other problems. You may need to repair or reset VS.

Will report back solution if I figure it out.

Comment: This solved it for me eventually : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41774824/vs2017-rc1-installation-installation-error-microsoft-portablelibrary-targeting/41774863#41774863

It is well worth it - the new functionality is really awesome