# VS2017 RC1 Installation installation error - Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi failed - No XAML

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I had errors installing VS2017 with

`Package 'Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi,version=15.0.26004.1' failed to install`

The actual IDE will open but I don't have any XAML functionality - it appeared to fail the installation before this component was installed. XAML files won't load and there is no XAML listed under 'Text Editor'.

[image]

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

After several hours finally managed to get it to work:

Still not sure *exactly* what a targeting pack is - and why VS couldn't install it but I manually installed this package and managed to get it to work:

- Manually installed:
  `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.2 Developer Pack and Language Packs`
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53321

Other things I did that may have contributed to the solution:

- I rebooted
- I removed all files in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages` - actually I moved them to an `OLD` folder and later deleted them. You will see packages downloaded here after you restart the install.
- I had previously created a symbolic link from `%ProgramData%\Package Cache` to another drive to save space (https://superuser.com/questions/455853/can-i-delete-the-folder-c-programdata-package-cache). This symbolic link didn't seem to work anymore leaving me with some files in `%ProgramData%\Package Cache` and the rest in the other drive. I moved them over and recreated the link. If this is something you did to save disk space and forgot then that could contribute towards a failed solution.

Something above fixed the issue and I now have `XAML` back again.

Note: The VS2017 RC1 does not support offline installation so that was another avenue I explored and gave up on. The command line switches currently do NOTHING.

I believe the package I needed is the following one but not absolutely sure.

> C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.PortableLibrary.TargetingPack.Msi,version=15.0.25719.0